# Dart - Hide method from parent class / call private method from parent class

Tags: dart

I have a class that extends another. The parent class is not intended to be used directly by the API rather it implements basic methods that are helpers for child classes.

When I use the child class in a program I can see all method from said class but also the one from the parent class that are not intended to be called directly, they exist to be called by the methods of the child class.

I tried to make parents method private. This would work I believe as long as parent and child are declared in the same library. But I have an issue with the "library" notion. I understand part/part of are somewhat depreciated, and I want the parent class to be in a specific file. I can't figure a way to do it with import/export.

Is there a way to either hide a public method from the parent class from all child classes usage or to make a private method from the parent class callable from all child classes ?

Best regards ;

Exemple:

myLib.dart

```dart
export mainClass.dart;
```

mainClass.dar

```dart
import baseClass.dart;

class MainClass extends BaseClass {
    publicFunc() => ... //Can't call _hiddenFunc, can call wantToHideFunc()

}
```

In a second file (for code reusability purposes)

```dart
class MainClass extends BaseClass {
    _hiddenFunc() => ...
    wantToHideFunc() => ...
}
```

Using myLib public API

```dart
import myLib.dart
main() {
    class = Class();
    class.publicFunc(); //Intended
    class.wantToHideFunc() //Wants to avoid...
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: Maybe using composition would be more appropriate for your use than inheritance?  Or just use `part` and `part of`.  AFAIK they're not going anywhere.

Comment: I added examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart does not have `protected` access like Java or C#.
You can't hide a public member, you can't access a private member from a different library, and there is no third option.

It sounds like you want members of the superclass which can be invoked only from subclasses, not from outside of the object. That's what's called `protected` in, e.g., Java, and Dart does not have anything similar to that.
The only level of privacy in Dart is library-private, which is chosen by starting the name with a `_`.

The reason that Dart has this design is that it was originally a very dynamic language. You can preform "dynamic invocations" on a value with static type `dynamic`, say `dynVal.foo(42)` and it will call the method of that name.
To make a name unreachable, it needed to be safe from dynamic invocation as well. Because of that, Dart privacy does not care where the code doing the invocation is, it only cares whether you know the name - and library private names are considered *different names* depending on which library they're from.

Using `part` is not discouraged for situations where it actually serves a purpose. If you can put the part into a library of its own, that's *better* because it allows it to have its own privacy and imports, but if you need the classes to share privacy, using part files to split up a large file is perfectly reasonable. It's a tool, there is nothing wrong with using it when it's the right tool for the job. A library is often a better tool for modularity, but not always.

Now, there is a *hack* you can use:

```dart
// Declare the base and provide extensions for "protected" members:
abstract class Base {
  int get _someHiddenStuff => 42;
  int get somePublicStuff => 37;
}
extension ProtectedBase on Base {
  int get someHiddenStuff => _someHiddenStuff;
}
```

Then import that in another library and do:

```dart
import "base.dart";
export "base.dart" hide ProtectedBase;
class SubClass extends Base {
  int doSomething => someHiddenStuff + somePublicStuff;
}
```

Then anyone importing "subclass.dart" will also get a version of `Base`, but they won't get the `ProtectedBase` extensions. Hiding the extensions from your package's public API will allow yourself to use it, but prevent your package's users from seeing the helper extensions.

(This is likely highly over-engineered, but it's an option. It's the evolution of the hack of having static/top-level helper functions that you don't export.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. And your workaround ! As for library privacy I'm not sure I understand if you say that there is no way to do it using import/export, or if you say that part/part of is the right tool for the job but import/export could work as well.

Comment: If you use library privacy for a feature, then all classes cooperating around that feature must be in the same library, which suggests either a single file, or splitting into parts. Imports won't work with that. If the solution doesn't use library privacy for the parts you use in the other classes (the extension approach doesn't), then you can use imports. Use parts if you *need* to, use imports if you don't.